# How to display separate page if quota is exceeded?

Tags: google-app-engine, quota

I do it in accordance with [Custom Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses) - app.yaml is updated with

```
error_handlers:
- error_code: over_quota
  file: templates/over_quota.html
```

and according file is created. But still error (exception) is shown instead of that page. I've tried to place the file in the root folder (with according update at app.yaml) - it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

**Upd**. I've defined that in the following way in accordance with @Gwyn Howell comment.

```
handlers:
- url: /over_quota.html
  static_files: templates/over_quota.html
  upload: templates/over_quota.html

error_handlers:
- error_code: over_quota
  file: over_quota.html
```

But (1) how to test it, (2) which url user will see in result? `http://www.example.com/over_quota.html` or will it be original url?

Comment: have you mapped templates/over_quota.html to a page handler in your app.yaml? What happens if you go to /templates/over_quota.html?

Comment: @GwynHowell, thanks for your help. The page is not displayed if I go to /templates/over_quota.html. And I haven't defined page handler. How should it look like? I am reading https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Pattern_Handlers, but it doesn't help me. What will be the url user will see? Will it be original url or some other?

Comment: @GwynHowell, please post your comment as the answer. I've also updated the question.

Comment: sorry man i was mistaken - you don't need to map to handlers. they should just map as static files. A key clue from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Custom_Error_Responses says "Make sure that the path to the error response file does not overlap with static file handler paths." - could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going over a specific quota, such as datastore operations, which throws an exception, without going over your instance hours quota. The over quota error message is only shown if App Engine can't send a request to an instance at all due to lack of quota; if the request is sent to your app, but you attempt to do something that exceeds available quota, it's up to you to handle the exception as you see fit.

Comment: Ooh, that wasn't quite clear for me from the Custom Error Responses description...

Comment: @LA_ A good rule of thumb is that App Engine will never provide its own response once it's sent a request to one of your instances. This is why the 404 handler doesn't handle 404s resulting from application routing, for instance.

Comment: @NickJohnson Does this mean, if I am sending, all urls(.*) to a script, then I will have to handle 404 errors in the script itself?